# How can I put a background image on a circle component?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, styled-components

I wrote the code below which makes for me a circle with a partial red and green border. It was shown in the first photo.

Now my question is how can I fill the circle inside with a picture? I mean something like `background-image: url("");`. Can I do the same with `fill` attribute (now it is `transparent`)? The circle should look like on the second picture (the picture is just an example). I am using React and styled-components.

```
const Wrapper = styled.svg`
  position: relative;
`;

const BottomCircle = styled.circle`
  stroke: ${({ theme }) => theme.red};
  stroke-width: 5px;
  stroke-dasharray: 440;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  fill: transparent;
`;

const TopCircle = styled.circle`
  stroke: ${({ theme }) => theme.green};
  stroke-width: 5px;
  stroke-dasharray: 440;
  stroke-dashoffset: 250;
  fill: transparent;
`;

const Holder = styled.g``;

<Wrapper width="200" height="200">
    <Holder transform="rotate(-90 100 100)">
       <BottomCircle r="70" cx="100" cy="100"></BottomCircle>
       <TopCircle r="70" cx="100" cy="100"></TopCircle>
    </Holder>
</Wrapper>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: What you're trying to do is called image masking check out this link for reference:

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/m/mask-image/

Comment: but I have nothing to set inside ```mask-image```

Comment: Does this need to be done with an SVG? You can do this with an `img` then have a `:before` and `:after` for the red/green borders.

Comment: I want to set the percentage for the circle to fill the green bar and I can do this by ```stroke-dashoffset```. I don't need to do this with ```svg``` if it is possible with ```img```, ```before``` and ```after```. Can You show me how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would approach this. Use a `div` with a conic gradient with an image on top to mask it.

```
const Avatar = styled.div`
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: ${({ Progress }) => {
    if (Progress)
      return `conic-gradient(red ${(Progress / 100) * 360}deg, yellow ${
        (Progress / 100) * 360
      }deg 360deg)`;
  }};

  &:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 5px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: calc(100% - 10px);
    height: calc(100% - 10px);
    background-image: ${({ ImageSrc }) => {
      if (ImageSrc) return `url(${ImageSrc})`;
    }};
    background-position: center;
    background-size: contain;
  }
`;

<Avatar Progress={80} ImageSrc="https://i.pinimg.com/474x/ea/82/5f/ea825f48a30b953a396a29a54752ff68.jpg"/>
```

[image: demo]